How to reopen an incorrectly closed question in Staging Ground?
I have a question that (IMO) was incorrectly closed in the Staging Ground. If the post had made it to the public site, it could be voted on to be reopened, but as far as I can tell, a post closed in Staging is effectively dead.
help/reopen-questions only seems to relate to posts that get past Staging.
What is the proper protocol for re-opening a post in staging, and can it be added to the linked post?

This question is similar to: How do I submit my Staging Ground question for re-evaluation?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem. Specifically, I mention: "The process to get your question looked at again is the same as "Requires major changes"

I agree it's a duplicate. This sites search function leaves much to be desired.

If your question is closed in the Staging Ground and you feel it is incorrect, then just like what we're supposed to do on the main site you should edit the question and address the problem specified by the closure reason. Make sure to submit the question for re-evaluation when submitting your edit (there should be a checkbox from what I understand).
Once you've submitted your question for re-evaluation your question will go into the re-evaluation state where it will once again be shown to reviewers, if a reviewer feels your question is suitable or the closure was incorrect they just need to leave a review which is not "Decline re-evaluation" and your post will get reopened.
